# Change background color on visible accordian h3 tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have the following in html

```
 <li id="options">
     <h3><span class=""></span>Options</h3>
         <ul id="childPo">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="eight columns">
                     <span class="form-required">*</span>
                     <span id="error-pi-first-name"></span>   
                     <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
                </div>   
            </div>
          </ul>
  </li>

<li id="personalize_front" class="active">
    <h3><span class="#"></span>Personalize</h3>
       <ul id="childPf">
           <div class="container">
             blah blah

           </div>
       </ul>
 </li>
```

In my javascript i have

```
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

What i need now is anytime the accordian is open whichever one is open i want to change the background color on the h3 tag

Comment: It's accordiOn, not accordiAn :)

Comment: I don't get it, there's no instance of accordion/an in your html

Comment: I don't get it, there's no try of changing the background color or className

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the background colour of your <h3> element, however it looks like you already have an "active" class on it's parent <li> element. That's probably what you want to target with JQuery and CSS.

```js
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
   
    $("#accordian h3").removeClass('highlight');
    
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
      
       $(this).addClass('highlight');
    
       $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordian"> 
    <ul>
        <li id="options">
             <h3><span class=""></span>Options</h3>
                 <ul id="childPo">
                    <div class="container">
        
                        <div class="eight columns">
                             <span class="form-required">*</span>
                             <span id="error-pi-first-name"></span>   
                             <input type="text" id="first-name" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                  </ul>
          </li>
        
        <li id="personalize_front" class="active">
            <h3><span class="#"></span>Personalize</h3>
               <ul id="childPf">
                   <div class="container">
                     blah blah
        
                   </div>
               </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and while i think it will work the only problem is see is that the actual color is not showing up.

In my css i have 
.accordion_highlight {
 background: #fdb415;
}

Comment: nevermind i had another div for h3 that had different background color

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

I'd achieve this by adding a class to your CSS to set the appropriate background colour.

Then add `$(this).addClass('newClassName');`

Assuming you want to remove the class when another h3 is clicked you might also want to use:

`$('h3.newClassName').removeClass('newClassName');` also.

You could just add the colour using the `.css` method - but using a class would make it easier to identify any `h3` already showing that background colour if needs removing.

Comment: I havent tried anything since i dont know what to add exactly